# How do I instantiate a new matrix every iteration?

Tags: java

I am doing a custom written javabat problem that requires me to compare set length groups of numbers. I will describe the problem in detail more if you need, but I want to know if there's a way to create a new matrix (with a new name every time; within a for loop) with the set length from the array's square rooted length (all arrays being passed in are perfect squares).

```
  for (int boxes = 0; boxes < matrixBox; boxes++)
  {
     String matrixName = "matrixLine" + boxes+""; 
     int []matrixName = new int[matrixBox]; // The compiler wants to make a new variable.
  }
```

I essentially need a new matrix with the names: matirixLine1, matrixLine2,...etc. so I can compare them later on to solve my problem.

Btw, this site is incredible.

Comment: That's not a matrix.  (Matricies are 2-dimensional)

Comment: yes, I meant an int array. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the arrays in an array (an `int[][]`)

For example:

```
int[][] data = new int[matrixBox][]; //Full of nulls

for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
   data[index] = new int[size]; 
}
```

Comment: I meant to ask how to create a new int array every time, but I'm kinda tired right now. How could I use a matrix to compare data and how do I set it up? I haven't needed to use one yet.

Comment: It's useful, but I need to try later. I need some sleep. Thanks. (p.s. the example didn't show up before)